# How can I find out why mongodb crashes?

Tags: mongodb

I have recently started having my mongodb instance crash on an ubuntu machine at random times,  it usually stays up for a day or so. The mongo log has no trace of the crash, just the last operation and when I restarted the server. I need some guidance in finding out the problem and the log doesn't have any information. Is there another log I should be looking at?

The setup is fairly straightforward, single instance (no sharding), of mongodb 2.2 running on an ubuntu box, with pretty much default install.

The only change I have done recently which seems to coincide with this in timing is I have replaced some simple map reduce execution with the aggregate framework.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you know it's crashing if there is nothing in the logs?  What -is- the last thing in the logs?   If I had to guess - possibly being killed on the OS level?

Comment: because the process isn't running i was assuming that it was crashing. the last thing i see in the mongo log is an update query. assuming that you are right, that the OS would kill it, how would i find out why and how? also since this is a service, shouldn't it restart it?

Comment: I think the intent of a service is to restart it on machine start, not when it stops.  is it always the same update query that you see?  You can increase logging level - see if there is more information. Depending on what might be killing it there may not be any info or something in OS logs or dmesg - not sure there.

Comment: services can be setup automatically if they die/crash. there is nothing i can find in the os logs to indicate somehow some abnormal situation to make the OS decide to kill something (and what process in the OS would decide to do that?)

Comment: this one: http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer

Comment: thanks, never too old to learn. i have spent a couple of hours looking into whether i was running out of memory on machine. the problem is that none of the system log files are showing a killed process. all i know is that mongo is killed (now on a regular basis). i am suspecting that the  aggregation operations are using more memory that the map reduce version. i've started monitoring the memory and hopefully i be able to definitely say whether it is a memory problem or not.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky That's a good reply and worth posting as an answer. Mongo is unusually memory hungry (even for a DB) and silent deaths can often be memory related as this catches people unawares.

Comment: ran out of swap? Try upping the amount of swap.

Comment: You may get information about the OS killing the process by seeing the output of dmesg . Simply type dmesg in your linux console.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB unofficially have Mtools try download and run with your logs in this tool. it can give you why it went down, how many time it restarted and many more details.
you can get this in github

Answer (score 1):

Through Logs you can view the actual cause of crash

```
/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log  ####Common path of logs
 or use this command                   

db.adminCommand( { getLog : "global" } )
```